# Do I have to initialize Option type in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the different between `Option[String]` and `Option[String] = None`? I think Option type is default to `None` if not set, but not 100% sure. Wondering if there will be any potential impact.

For example:

```
case class User(name:Option[String])
```

Will it be different from

```
case class User(name:Option[String]=None)
```

Comment: Can you show a code example? Is your `Option` a local variable, a member, or what else?

Comment: `Option[A]` is not a value. It's a type. It doesn't make sense to say it's `None` by default. It is only `Some[A]` or `None` after it has been instantiated.

Comment: @Suma edited, thanks.

Comment: In `case class User(name:Option[String]=None)`, `None` is the default argument for `name`. It means you don't have to specify that parameter when instantiating a `User`, and when you don't, it will be `None`.

Comment: @marstran edited, thanks.

Comment: @marstran yes, but will it be different from `case class User(name:Option[String])`? Are they essentially equivalent?

Comment: With `name:Option[String] = None` you can write `val u = User()`. Without `None` same code will not compile. You will be forced to pass the name: `val u = User("Name")`

Comment: Also, that doesn't mean, that `None` is the only default value. You can use any other value of type `Option[String]` as the default. `case class User(name:Option[String]=Some("My Favorite Default Name"))`

Comment: Your assumption is not correct: `Option` trait was mainly design for return values. Instead of having input *optional* parameters, I suggest you to overload the method with different signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you confuse two different concepts: *Default arguments* and *Default initial values*.

**Default arguments**

In Scala you can provide default arguments for parameters of methods and constructors. And it allows you to skip those arguments:

```
case class User(name:Option[String]=Some("Sam")) {
  def say(greeting: String = "Hello"): String = greeting + " " + name
}

val u = new User
println(u.say())
```

As you can see, it has nothing to do with `Option` and `None`. It works for any type (see the method) and yes, you have to specify that default yourself, otherwise it will not compile:

```
case class User(name:Option[String])
val u = new User
// Doesn't compile.
```

And no, `None` is not the default value for `Option[A]` when we talk about default arguments. You can provide `None` as well as any other value of type `Option[A]` as a parameter of type `Option[A]`, but you have to do it explicitly:

```
case class User(name:Option[String]=Some("Sam"))
case class User(name:Option[String]=None)
```

So, *talking about parameters to methods and constructors*, there's no default value for values of type `Option[A]`. You must specify that default yourself, otherwise it will not compile.

So, these two lines from your question are indeed different:

```
case class User(name:Option[String])
case class User(name:Option[String]=None)
```

**Default initial values**

Consider this code:

```
var name: Option[String] = _
println(name)
```

`null` is printed. Because the default value is `null`, not `None`. And this is the case not only for `Option[A]`, but for all `AnyRef` types in Scala. The following prints `null` either:

```
var name: String = _
println(name)
```

Please, refer also to Scala Language Specification. E.g. https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is incorrect. There is no standard default for parameters; usually, parameters that are declared must also be provided explicitly when the method or constructor is called.

But a parameter can be declared as optional, and supplied with a default value at its declaration point: When you declare a parameter with its name and type, and then you add the equals sign followed by a static value, then this parameter becomes optional. If left out, the given static value will be inserted automatically.

This does not only work with case classes, but also with other kinds of constructors and methods.

In the first example that you have given, a statement like `val user = User()` would not compile, because the `name` parameter *must* be given.

In the second example, `val user = User()` would very well compile. At runtime, `user.name` would have the value of `None`.

Comment: I think it was already answered in comments. And the assumption is indeed incorrect, because `None` is not the default value for `Option[String]`.

Comment: @zhelezoglo so that means, there will be no default value automatically assigned to Option[String]. Is that correct?

Comment: @zhelezoglo Thanks for the observation! I corrected the answer; please check.

Comment: Proper answers to a question should be provided as an actual _answer_. A comment cannot be marked as accepted by the person who asked the question. So that means, when a question has been "answered" in the comments, it still counts as unanswered by StackOverflow. One should still provide a proper answer for such cases.